# Conditional formatting issue in 2007 version

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In excel 2003,when i **select** range of cells in a column and goto conditional formatting and given a formula that checks cell value in a given range.(**cell address i gave as first cell address**).

After applying that,other cells' conditional formats formula also updated with their addresses.

But when i do same thing in 2007 version,conditional formatting is applied but conditional formatting formula showing first cell address only.

Please suggest some workaround.

**Edit:Some more details with example**

Say,i have a column with values 1 to 8 at A2 to A9 cells.
i select range A2:A9 and goto conditional formatting and gave formula as

> =IF(A2<>"--",NOT(AND((VALUE(A2)>=1),(VALUE(A2)<=5))),FALSE)

i clicked on ok after selecting formatting colour and it worked (in both 2003 and 2007).

Now the actual issue is,when i go back to individual cells and watch conditional formatting formula,here what i observed.

In 2003,it is (x is place holder i put,x is from 2 to 9)

> =IF(Ax<>"--",NOT(AND((VALUE(Ax)>=1),(VALUE(Ax)<=5))),FALSE)

But in 2007,it is fixed as

> =IF(A2<>"--",NOT(AND((VALUE(A2)>=1),(VALUE(A2)<=5))),FALSE)

Hope i am clear in my question now.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are referring to. Can you post a screen shot of the problem or give an example of the formula?

Comment: @ CharlieRB,i edited my question and added example.pl.go through once

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 and up recognize you've selected a range and want the formula applied to the range. This is shown in the `Applies to` box of the rules manager.

[image]

Excel then applies the formula in an applicable manor to the cells in the range. The formula does not need to be different for each cell in the range.

Unless the rule is not working properly or is giving you an error (which you have not indicated), there is nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: @ CharlieRB,those individual format conditions formulas are used in further analysis  in one reporting application.At the time we develop that application,we used 2003 version,so everything worked as expected.But now since individual cell's formula address not updated,our analysis results are getting wrong.

Comment: Those details are important when asking the initial question. I have no way of knowing what that application is, what it does or how it was developed. Therefore, there is no way I can tell you how to work around it.

Comment: @CharlieB,that application "uses" those cells' conditional formatting formulas only,rest is simple analysis that doesnt affect these formulas or anything related to worksheet.